# Summation of two matrices multiplied with conditional indexing

Tags: matlab, nested-loops, linear-algebra

I have a question about efficiently coding a linear algebra problem in Matlab. The problem is:

[image: Equation definition]

A similar problem is defined as:

[Similar problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7Hkn.png)

This ends up being a block diagonal sum, followed by a sum along the diagonals of each summed block diagonal. The following code computes this computation in a vectorized manner, utilizing [this code](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/115340-block-transposition-permutation-and-reshaping-of-arrays) on the Matlab FEX.

```
temp = oneStep(R,presums(1),presums(2));
temp = oneStep(temp,1,presums(1));
temp = reshape(temp,2*presums(1)-1,2*presums(2)-1);

function Y = oneStep(X,p,q)
%p - blocklength
%q - length of matrix, counted in blocks
    Y = blkReshape(X,[p,p],1,q^2,[]);
    Y = pagemtimes(reshape(Y,p^2,q^2,[]),summationMatrix(q));
  
    Y = reshape(Y,p,p,[]);
  
end

function S = summationMatrix(q)
%q - length of matrix, counted in blocks
    T = toeplitz(0:-1:1-q,0:q-1);
    S = double(T(:)==(1-q:q-1));
end
```

I'm wondering if there's an extension of this above code to my new problem. If looping over `alpha` and `beta` is necessary, that's fine, but ultimately vectorizing this code similar to the previous case would be ideal. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have implemented the series of summations with for loops and conditionals and the proof of concept works, but it needs to be more efficient because this will be done hundreds of times.

Here is code that produces what I want.

```
A = randn(8,8)+1i*randn(8,8);
data = randn(16,16) + 1i*randn(16,16);
presums = size(A);
A = repmat(A,8,8);
idx = [8 8];
out = foo(data,A,idx);

function out = foo(data,A,idxs)
k = 0:idxs(1)-1;
l = k;
p = 0:idxs(2)-2;
q = p;
t = (idxs(1)):size(data,1)-1;
s = (idxs(2)):size(data,2)-1;
a = 1:size(data,1);
b = 1:size(data,2);
out = zeros(size(data));

for aa = a
    for bb = b
        for tt = t
            for kk = k
                if tt - kk == aa 
                    for ss = s
                        for pp = p
                            if ss - pp == bb
                                for qq = q
                                    for ll = l
                                        out(aa,bb) = out(aa,bb) + A(kk+idxs(1)*(pp)+1,ll+idxs(1)*(qq)+1)*...
                                            data(tt-ll+1,ss-qq+1);
                                    end
                                end
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end

end
```

Comment: I think it would be useful if you showed your code. It often is easier to simplify or vectorized existing code than translating an equation to code. And it gives something to compare to, to ensure our interpretation matches yours.

Comment: Alright, I'll edit the original question.

Comment: Well, for starters, `for kk = k, if tt - kk == aa` can be replaced with `kk = tt - aa`. Similarly for `pp`.

Comment: This broke it with an exceeding array bounds error.

Comment: Maybe you need to verify that the computed `kk` is in the list of values `k`: `if any(kk == k) ...` or `if kk>=0 && kk<=k(end) ...`. In any case, looping over the whole list to find that one element where the condition is met is rather inefficient.

Comment: Your code would be improved with example inputs for `foo(data,A,idxs)` which can be tested

Comment: Okay, I will add those.

Comment: I just added random data, but the key is the presums values to do the indexing, so the size of these matrices are an example of what I might be looking for. If you want to use magic() for example, so that the values are constant, that should work.

Comment: Also, adding `if any(kk=k)` or something of that nature is essentially equivalent to having the sum over `k` and having a conditional.

Comment: `idxs` isn't specified.

Comment: Sorry, should be fixed now.